# How to tell of whether the kernel parameter [passed at command line] is a valid kernel parameter?

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel, parameter

In the `grub.conf` configuration file I can specify command line parameters that the kernel will use, i.e.:

```
kernel /boot/kernel-3-2-1-gentoo root=/dev/sda1 vga=791 plasticDuck
```

After booting up a given kernel, is there a way to tell if all parameters were passed 'correctly'?

I.e. there is no `plasticDuck` kernel parameter, but:

```
dmesg | grep plasticDuck
```

only returns:

```
Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda1 vga=791 plasticDuck
```

(no error)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question entirely. You want to know if a parameter was actually taken into account/acted on? (i.e. in your example, you'd like to know that `plasticDuck` was ignored since the actual kernel parameter is `plasticPenguin`, i.e. you got a typo.)

Comment: @Mat Exactly something like that. The background of the story: I have found the 'atkbd.softraw' kernel parameter and I this parameter works for kernels 2.6.x, but my kernel version is 3.2.12. And I'm wondering if I can still use that parameter or not.

Comment: Ok, understood. Don't know of anything generic though, sorry.

Comment: `vga` parameter is deprecated! but works for backward compatibility.

Comment: Valid? Looks like you just want to tell if it's actually used by kernel? If your see it in `/proc/cmdline`, it's being used, but whether it effects is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a command that lists built-in modules parameters and their values. If you know the path to the driver files you could list the parameters for that module e.g. if you used `ipv6.autoconf=0` as a kernel boot parameter you could run:

```
ls -1 /sys/module/ipv6/parameters/
autoconf
disable
disable_ipv6
```

and then, if the specified parameter is in the list (i.e. it is valid), check its value:

```
cat /sys/module/ipv6/parameters/autoconf 
0
```

Or, in your particular case - `atkbd`:

```
cat /sys/bus/serio/drivers/atkbd/serio0/softraw
1
```

As per [gilles post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48648), for loadable modules you could use `modinfo` to list specific parameters and possible values but that doesn't work for built-in modules (although there have been attempts [to add support](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/1/18/111) for built-in modules):

```
modinfo ipv6
modinfo: ERROR: Module ipv6 not found.
```

Comment: Is there any way I can apply this procedure to a built-in kernel module? (I can't switch the atkbd module so it is compiled as a module). By a built-in kernel module I mean a module that is 'hard-compiled' into the kernel - I can't even disable it (or I don't know how). And thanks for the 'module' part. I didn't know I can pass parameters to kernel modules, in comparison to the kernels 'core'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell whether a parameter is valid. Parameters passed to the kernel are also passed to modules (in addition to the parameters passed when loading the module itself), and maybe a module that you haven't loaded yet will understand this parameter.

The `modinfo` command lists the parameters that a module understands. You can see the parameters of a loaded module in `/sys/module/$module_name/parameteres/`. I am not aware of anything similar for the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/cmdline` file contains the parameters which were passed to the kernel.

Comment: Does this mean that `plasticDuck` does not show up in `cmdline`?

Comment: @Marco it still shows up in `cmdline`, even if 'not valid'.

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant to the question then.